# How to get Hours and Minute using Extract function as single result in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a timestamp with timezone column in one of my tables. I need to extract both hours and minutes from the timestamp with timezone column  using extract function but i am unable too.

I tried like this,

```
extract(hour_minute from immi_referral_user_tb.completed_time) >= '06:30'
```

but I am getting a syntax error.

I am using extract function in where clause

immi_referral_user_tb.completed_time = timestamp with timezone column

Is there any other way too accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the column to a time data type and compare that to a time value:

```
immi_referral_user_tb.completed_time::time >= time '06:30'
```